# Titanium Appcelerator : iPhone device install error - pnglib

Tags: iphone, deployment, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to install an iPhone app to an iPhone using Appcelerator Titanium 1.2.2 with SDK 1.6.2

The app ID matches the profile, runs fine on the simulator, but fails to install to the device with this error:

Install Error:

> [DEBUG] While reading /htdocs/titanium/EA/build/iphone/build/Release-iphoneos/EA.app/Default@2x.png pngcrush caught libpng error:
>   [ERROR] [ERROR] While reading /htdocs/titanium/EA/build/iphone/build/Release-iphoneos/EA.app/Default@2x.png pngcrush caught libpng error:
>   [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.6.2/iphone/builder.py", line 1238, in main
>       execute_xcode("iphoneos%s" % iphone_version,args,False)
>     File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.6.2/iphone/builder.py", line 1012, in execute_xcode
>       output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
>     File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.6.2/iphone/run.py", line 39, in run
>       sys.exit(rc)
>   SystemExit: 1

Any clues?

Thanks,
N.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify the file `reading /htdocs/titanium/EA/build/iphone/build/Release-iphoneos/EA.app/Default@2x.png` exists?

Also verify it is a PNG file by getting info on the file and make sure it has the extension `.png` and not something else hidden. You can also open it and save as a `png` file to hopefully fix the issue?